# How to sort results according to a specific list in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a Ruby hash that I want to filter and sort before iterating through it. The structure of the hash has dependencies, and when I iterate through, I need to do so in a specific order. So for example, with the following hash:

```
functionList = [
  {"name":"CreateDog"},
  {"name":"DeleteDog"},
  {"name":"UpdateDog"},
  {"name":"UpdateCat"},
  {"name":"DeleteCat"},
  {"name":"CreateCat"},
  {"name":"FindAnimals"},
  {"name":"Something"}
]
```

I want to filter for only Create, Update or Delete functions and loop through, which I had like this:

```
validReg="^(Create|Update|Delete)"
functionList.select{|s| s["name"].match(validReg)}.map{|m| m["name"]}.each do |fun|
  # invokeFunc(fun)
end
```

This returns the items I want, but in the naturally occurring order. However, the items have specific relationships to each other - Updates are dependent on Create and Deletes on Update. So I want to somehow sort the `functionList` some how. I cannot change how `functionList` is returned to me, and I need to control the sorting locally - e.g somewhere between the `.select` and `.each`.

I was thinking of doing something along the lines of  `["Create","Update","Delete"].each do |action| ....` approach, wondering if there's any "better" way of doing this (without looping and doing multiple searches) - some way of providing my own sort reference and calling sort on the array maybe?

To clarify the required final ordering for the iteration (`.each`):

I need all the `Creates` first for a given subject. The following sort order is fine: `CreateDog,CreateCat,CreateX` and then all `Updates`; or also can do by subject, e.g. sort order as `CreateDog,UpdateDog,DeleteDog,CreateCat,UpdateCat,DeleteCat`. So grouping by "verb" or by "subject" is fine, as long as the order of verbs is maintained is a pre-defined arbitrary order per subject

Comment: Please give us an example of your expected output. It's unclear what your dependance between "types" of records actually means.

Comment: Meager - I commented out `invokeFunc(fun)` but the idea is that I do something with each of the results. However, I need to always use `CreateDog` before `UpdateDog` - so I need all the `Create`s first for a given subject. It is fine if I do `CreateDog, CreateCat, CreateX` and then all the updates for subjects; or also can do by subject, e.g. sort order as  `CreateDog,UpdateDog,DeleteDog,CreateCat,UpdateCat`. So grouping by "verb" or by "subject" is fine, as long as the order of verbs is maintained per subject - if that makes sense....

Comment: Your own code *doesn't* work, since your hashes don't have `"name"` keys.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid multiple searches, loop through the list once and create a new hash keyed by phased and whose values are a list of functions for that phase. Then you can iterate through the phases and lists.

This means you only iterate through the functionList once and you have a data structure that's easier to work with in phases.

```
functionList = [
  {"name":"CreateDog"},
  {"name":"DeleteDog"},
  {"name":"DeletedDog"},
  {"name":"UpdateDog"},
  {"name":"UpdateCat"},
  {"name":"DeleteCat"},
  {"name":"CreateCat"},
  {"name":"FindAnimals"},
  {"name":"Something"}
]

phases = ["create", "update", "delete"]
phaseRe = %r{^(Create|Update|Delete)[[:upper:]]}

phaseFunctions = Hash.new()

functionList.each do |func|
    match = phaseRe.match(func[:name])
    if match
        (phaseFunctions[match[1].downcase] ||= []) << func
    end
end

# In case any of the phases are empty.
# Can't set it earlier or everything will go into the default array.
phaseFunctions.default = []

phases.each do |phase|
    phaseFunctions[phase].each do |func|
        puts "#{phase} #{func}"
    end
end
```

Comment: A Stack Exchange history question in the right margin caught my eye:  "...Russian fleet suspects Japanese torpedo boats...". I was surprised to find that you authored the lone answer. Your interests seem to be wide-ranging.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks! Wait til you look at WorldBuilding.SE. :)

Answer (score 2):

**By operation**

```
ops = %w| Create Update Delete |
  #=> ["Create", "Update", "Delete"]
functionList.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) do |g,h|
  op = g[:name][/\A[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?=[[:upper:]])/]
  h[op] << g[:name] if ops.include?(op)
end.values_at(*ops).flatten
  #=> ["CreateDog", "CreateCat", "UpdateDog", "UpdateCat",
  #    "DeleteDog", "DeleteCat"]
```

**By subject**

```
subs = %w| Dog Cat |
  # => ["Dog", "Cat"]
functionList.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) do |g,h|
  sub = g[:name][/(?<=[[:lower:]])[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\z/]
  h[sub] << g[:name] if subs.include?(sub)
end.values_at(*subs).flatten
  #=> ["CreateDog", "DeleteDog", "UpdateDog", "UpdateCat",
  #    "DeleteCat", "CreateCat"]
```

**Single method**

One could of course combine these into a single method.

```
def group_em(function_list, items, regex)
  function_list.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) do |g,h|
    item = g[:name][regex]
    h[item] << g[:name] if items.include?(item)
  end.values_at(*items).flatten
end

group_em(functionList, ops, /\A[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?=[[:upper:]])/)
  #=> ["CreateDog", "CreateCat", "UpdateDog", "UpdateCat",
  #    "DeleteDog", "DeleteCat"]
group_em(functionList, subs, /(?<=[[:lower:]])[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\z/)
  #=> ["CreateDog", "DeleteDog", "UpdateDog", "UpdateCat",
  #    "DeleteCat", "CreateCat"]
```

**Alternative method**

[Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) could be used instead of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), in which case the method would be as follows.

```
def group_em(function_list, items, regex)
  function_list.group_by { |g| g[:name][regex] }.
                values_at(*items).
                flatten.
                map { |g| g[:name] }
end
```

For the operations case, the first step is to compute the following hash.

```
function_list.group_by do |g|
  g[:name][/\A[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?=[[:upper:]])/]
end
  #=> {"Create"=>[{:name=>"CreateDog"}, {:name=>"CreateCat"}],
  #    "Delete"=>[{:name=>"DeleteDog"}, {:name=>"DeleteCat"}],
  #    "Update"=>[{:name=>"UpdateDog"}, {:name=>"UpdateCat"}],
  #    "Find"=>[{:name=>"FindAnimals"}],
  #    "Something"=>[{:name=>"Something"}]}
```

**Explanation**

The steps in the "by operation" case are as follows.

```
by_op = functionList.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |g,h|
  op = g[:name][/\A[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?=[[:upper:]])/]
  h[op] << g[:name] if ops.include?(op)
end
  #=> {"Create"=>["CreateDog", "CreateCat"],
  #    "Delete"=>["DeleteDog", "DeleteCat"],
  #    "Update"=>["UpdateDog", "UpdateCat"]}
arr = by_op.values_at(*ops)
  #=> [["CreateDog", "CreateCat"], ["UpdateDog", "UpdateCat"],
  #    ["DeleteDog", "DeleteCat"]]
arr.flatten
 #=> ["CreateDog", "CreateCat", "UpdateDog", "UpdateCat",
 #    "DeleteDog", "DeleteCat"]
```

The calculation of `by_op` is essentially a compact version of the following.

```
by_op = {}
functionList.each do |g|
  op = g[:name][/\A[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?=[[:upper:]])/]
  if ops.include?(op)
    by_op[op] = [] unless by_op.key?(op)
    by_op[op] << g[:name]
  end
end
by_op
```

The regular expression reads, "Match the beginning of the string (`\A`) followed by one upper case letter, then one or more lower case letters, followed by an upper case letter that is not part of the match". `(?=[[:upper:]])` is a *positive lookahead*.

For an explanation of `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }` see the doc for the case where `new` takes a block at [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Answer (score 1):

Do `sort_by { |s| 'CUD'.index(s[0]) }` before the `each`.

Or `sort_by { |s| s[1] }.reverse`.

Or `sort_by { |s| s[3] + s[0] }`.

Not very serious about the latter two. But the first one is good, I think.

Btw, you can save some code/work if you `map` before you `select`.